# npm packaging without an entry point

Tags: node.js, npm, entry-point, npm-publish

I plan to publish a JavaScript library as an npm package and I have a question regarding packages entry points and best practices: what would be the best practice when a package doesn't expose a single entry point?

1. Explicitly declare `exports` without `main`
2. Declare `exports` with `main` that would point to an `index.js` that would throw some helpful error message explaining how to consume the lib

My lib only is only compatible with node > 14 and we use the `exports` property to leverage subpath exports (as it's shipped both as ESM/CJS module format)

As declared, the library doesn't expose a single entry point and is meant to be consumed by importing a default export from a specific file. So the consumer would use the following semantics to import:

```
// ESM
import Foo from 'my-lib/path/filename1';
```

```js
// CJS
const Foo = require('my-lib/path/filename1');
```